# Tests getting failed in jenkins but getting passed in my local

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, partcover

I am trying to run partcover with jenkins for code coverage report. Before it was working fine and all tests were passing successfully but now some tests are getting failed(with jenkins) which are passing successfully in my local.Can anybody suggest how to check the reason for the tests failing in the jenkins?

Comment: What's showing up in the logs?   I'd first look for test data that is expected but missing.

Comment: Is the problem with part cover or Jenkins, try running the tests without partcover to cut down the variables in your situation.

Comment: I have tried to run tests in my local and its getting passed there, but its showing failed in Jenkins.i have tried to run partcover  locally with my code as well but it also doesn't work and giving following error:            "System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040153): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FB20430E-CDC9-45D7-8453-272268002E08} failed due to the following error: 80040153."

Comment: When I use "/noisolation" option with MSTest.exe, the coverage is calculated but it MSTest.exe fails to let my test library access its config file. Application config loads MSTest.exe.config since "/noisolation" makes it run all tests within "MSTest" process itself.
If I do not use "/noisolation" option, PartCover can not calculate the coverage.
Can you please resolve this issue and make PartCover calculate the coverage using MSTest.exe without "/noisolation" option?

Comment: Its working fine if i am using Opencover instead of Partcover and not putting noisolation to AssemblyPath.Should be some issue with partcover tool.